# Visual Studio 2019 missing SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2019, sqlclr

I have installed VS 2019 with only the "Data storage and processing" option in the Workloads selection. However, after creating a new "SQL Server Database Project" there is no "SQL Server" section under "Project | Add New Item | Installed". The VS2019 installation did install "SQL Server Data Tools" so I am at a loss as to why there is no SQL Server section in Add New Item.

Which workload do I need to install to have SQL Server show in "Project | Add New Item | Installed" in VS2019? I also have SQL Server 2019 installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try selecting following options under "Cloud, database, and
server" from Individual Components tab while modifying the VS 2019 installation through Visual Studio Installer:

1. Data sources for Sql server support
2. SQL server data tools

Comment: That was it. The "Data storage and processing" Workflow installs the data tools components but not the data sources components.  Thanks. (+1)

Comment: Happy to help :)